# list jobs amazon aws elastic transcoding code php

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created pipeline from aws account , i am trying to create job by php code

**Now i want to list created(existing) job** , please suggest me any php function or code to list job by pipeline or by status . after getting list of job my next task is to transcode videos.

Thanks , 
Bakul P.Damodariya

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PHP class for working with Amazon Elastic Transcoder:

https://github.com/LPology/ElasticTranscoderPHP

To list jobs by pipeline:

```
$jobs = AWS_ET::listJobsByPipeline($pipelineId);
```

To list jobs by status:

```
$jobs = AWS_ET::listJobsByStatus($status);
```